# How can I use Maps in Java to list

Tags: java, list, maps

I'm doing a program that manages a newspaper. I have a List of aricles (List) and each Article has a theme and a subject.I want to output them, first by alphabetic order of the theme, then by alfabetic order of the subject, in different operations. How can I do that using Maps?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post some of code of what you tried ?

Comment: Are you required to use a Map? Did you consider other possibilities?

Comment: If you have List, sort it using custom comparators, one based on the theme other based on the subject of the article

Comment: Check out interface [`Comparator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: This looks like a homework question; but in any case (whether it is or not), please post a specific problem, and what you've tried so far, and what specific (incorrect) result you are currently receiving, and what you expect.

Comment: and know after this i dont know how to use it to write in the eclipse console all the articles by subject and by topic


private SortedMap<String, List<Articles>>listbytopic;
 
 public CaparicaPost2Class(){
  
  reports = new ArrayList<Articles>();
  chronicles = new ArrayList<Articles>();
  this.listbytopic= new TreeMap<String, List <Articles>>();

 }

Comment: Please don't try to write code in a comment.  If you have information that clarifies your question, *edit* your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Map is not required.

```
    List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... add articles
    articles.stream()
        .sorted((a, b) -> a.theme.compareTo(b.theme))
        .forEach(article -> { /* output an article */});
    articles.stream()
        .sorted((a, b) -> a.subject.compareTo(b.subject))
        .forEach(article -> { /* output an article */});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that kind of code is not what we use in class so I dont think its a good idea to put it in a school work..